# Background color formula error replacing 0's with black lines

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, crystal-reports

I'm having an issue where on my crystal report, summary schedule, where I have to highlight certain rows based on a math formula to see if it's over a percentage. 
https://gyazo.com/e741da6709a9d7f29d37d26340b909f7

```
IF {@dspNeed} <> 0 THEN 
     if 1-(({@dspStkWip}+{tblItem.OnOrderQuantity})/{@dspNeed}) > .15 
     then craqua
     else crnocolor
```

is the formula. When I run the preview I end up getting black lines where 0's would be. My problem is that the formula I'm using is to also make `If` because the divider can be a 0 sometimes. I do not know how to fix the black lines error but if anyone can help that would be nice.

Comment: Can you elaborate more what will result in '0'? And what is stopping you from adding a condition check for zero?

Comment: I'm new to this kind of programming.  I don't know how to add a condition for this. so the need build/buy will say zero if we dont need the order because we have it in stock. But I just dont want an eyesore of black lines to look at. Some of the black lines are covering what when we actually need to buy. Just let me know what you need info wise and I can help with it.

Comment: Ok I fixed my issue I forgot to put another else statement after the other else, then just put crnocolor which fixed my issue